# How to prevent fork bomb?

Tags: rhel, freeze, resources, ulimit

To prevent fork bomb I followed this http://www.linuxhowtos.org/Tips%20and%20Tricks/ulimit.htm

`ulimit -a` reflects the new settings but when I run (as `root` in `bash`) `:(){ :|:&};:` the VM still goes on max CPU+RAM and system will freeze.

How to ensure users will not be bring down the system by using fork bombs or running a buggy application?

OS: RHEL 6.4

Comment: I can't reproduce it here. Are you trying that as `root` by any chance? Which shell are you trying it from? (the missing space after `{` suggests `zsh` but I can't reproduce it there either).

Comment: Stephane Chazelas:
1] I was running as root, I tried it with normal user it works.
2] The missing space is typo, I'm using bash.Sorry.

3] Is it that ulimit cannot moderate the 'root' user?

Comment: @stephane-chazelas
1] I was running as root, I tried it with normal user it works.
2] The missing space is typo, I'm using bash.Sorry.

3] Is it that ulimit cannot moderate the 'root' user?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The superuser or any process with the CAP_SYS_ADMIN or CAP_SYS_RESOURCE capabilities are not affected by that limitation, that's not something that can be changed. `root` can always fork processes.

If some software is not trusted, it should not run as `root` anyway.

Comment: Unless it does something special, pretty much nothing should run as root anyways. root is the account you use when you're tired of trying to figure out what privileges/rights you need to figure it out or some fundamental system service.

Answer (score 15):

To make this change pervasive you'll need to add these limits to the entire environment. Changes using the `ulimit` command are only to the current environment.

**NOTE:** This will have no effect on the root user!

#### Example

Edit this file: `vi /etc/security/limits.conf` and add entries to the file limiting the number of processes (`nproc`) that a specific user or group of users' is allowed to have.

```
vivek hard nproc 300
@student hard nproc 50
@faculty soft nproc 100
@pusers hard nproc 200
```

**NOTE:** There are more examples in that file. Be careful with using the "all" (aka. `*`) this will limit system accounts too.

#### References

- [How to: Prevent a fork bomb by limiting user process](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-limiting-user-process.html)

Comment: While "all" will limit system accounts, most services that are ran by those system accounts do not pass through `pam_limits`.

Comment: Is it that ulimit cannot moderate the 'root' user?

Comment: Just as a general idea for adding more to the post, you might want to add something about [pam_cgroup](http://serverfault.com/questions/262296/how-is-the-cgroup-pam-module-configured) to the post since the OP's platform supports it and `pam_limits` will eventually be replaced by that once cgroups gain wider adoption.

Comment: Plus, since it sounds like the OP is playing around with resource usage policies, `cgroups` would give them better knobs for network and CPU utilization.