# Strange empty bash_history-*.tmp files in my $HOME folder

Tags: linux, bash, debian, shell

There are exactly 169 empty `.bash_history-*.tmp` in my home folder that were created on the same day (April 16 2021) without my knowledge. Files have only read and write permission for the owner. I am not sure what made this to happen. It has never happened in 5 years of my Linux journey(Both desktop and servers). Even stranger thing is that my default shell is not bash but its `zsh`. It would be great if someone could help me figure out what actually happened(if possible) or has it happened to someone else before? thank you in advance. Here it is

```bsh
.-(~)(user@host)
`-->> find . -name '.*.tmp'
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-01407.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-01810.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-02487.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-03675.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-08255.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-08260.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-08283.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-08326.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-08434.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-08450.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-08550.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-08581.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-08649.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-08676.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-08683.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-08697.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-08698.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-08712.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-08717.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-08742.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-08743.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-08819.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-08841.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-08878.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-08884.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-08904.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-08914.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-08962.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-09060.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-09116.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-09157.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-09201.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-09212.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-09228.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-09247.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-09248.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-09265.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-09274.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-09283.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-09331.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-09366.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-09397.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-09445.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-09501.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-09507.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-09548.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-09597.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-09632.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-09701.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-09760.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-09904.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-09992.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-10059.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-10158.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-10166.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-10170.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-10320.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-10536.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-10594.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-10631.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-10714.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-10753.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-11127.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-11189.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-11494.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-11514.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-11697.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-11774.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-11827.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-11973.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-12002.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-12266.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-12316.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-12331.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-12357.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-12377.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-12393.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-12399.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-12400.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-12405.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-12413.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-12417.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-12435.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-12475.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-12513.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-12563.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-12644.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-12648.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-12656.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-12743.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-12779.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-12801.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-12803.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-12817.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-12868.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-12971.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-13005.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-13013.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-13020.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-13033.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-13042.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-13047.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-13065.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-13074.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-13089.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-13090.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-13092.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-13094.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-13097.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-13099.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-13145.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-13162.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-13184.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-13202.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-13203.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-13206.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-13208.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-13218.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-13219.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-13220.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-13250.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-13313.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-13316.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-13320.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-13322.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-13323.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-13341.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-13360.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-13388.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-13489.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-13530.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-13566.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-13575.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-13576.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-13630.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-13640.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-13675.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-13717.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-14153.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-14156.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-14167.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-14204.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-14254.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-14256.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-14265.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-14267.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-14331.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-14332.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-14359.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-14368.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-14693.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-14792.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-14922.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-14923.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-14928.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-14931.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-14933.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-14943.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-14947.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-14951.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-14955.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-14968.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-30961.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-31005.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-31110.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-31142.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-32057.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-32358.tmp
-rw-------   1 user user   0 Apr 16 17:40 .bash_history-32434.tmp
```

FYI: someone helped me find a similar post on [archlinuxforum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=236034) but it doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `bash` source (available on Debian with `apt-get source bash`) writes its history file using the function `history_do_write` in the file `bash-5.0/lib/readline/histfile.c`. It creates a temporary file, writes the history lines to that, and then uses this to replace the actual history file

```
tempname = (overwrite && exists && S_ISREG (finfo.st_mode)) ? history_tempfile (histname) : 0;
output = tempname ? tempname : histname;

...

if (rv == 0 && histname && tempname)
  rv = histfile_restore (tempname, histname);
```

There are a number of places where the write could fail, and in these instances the temporary file is unlinked (deleted) and the original left alone.

However, you mentioned in [a passing comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/647708/strange-empty-bash-tmp-files-in-my-home-folder?noredirect=1#comment1214090_647709) that you ran a forkbomb. This could well have been the underlying cause of these temporary files. It's possible that with the extreme memory and process pressure triggered by the uncontrolled forkbomb, `bash` wasn't able to get enough temporary memory to complete even this recovery process and simply crashed out during the attempted update. (Please note that this isn't hard fact, just a hypothesis.)

If you are in an environment where it's likely users will run forkbombs, it's worth [enabling resource control](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85415/100397).

Comment: This makes sense, I ran the bash forkbomb after making sure that it would fail by limiting the resources for the non-superusers. Forkbomb ran as expected but it failed to shutdown(slowdown) the system. I will try to recreate the same scenario and will update the post if I succeed to create those tmp files again.

Comment: Welp!! I was successful in reproducing the exact scenario. I can confirm that when you run a bash forkbomb on a system running `debian 10 buster`  and when it succeeds to crash bash( it won't happen if you enable strict resource control policies for the users)  it will produce a bunch of `.bash_history-*.tmp` files in the `$HOME` dir. I would like to thank you @roaima, you were right.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to say for sure, but most likely something changed the `HISTFILE` environment variable and then called bash (or maybe some other `readline`-based file, but then the question would be why `$HISTFILE` would contain `.bash-history`).

This sounds like something you'd do in a unit test (suite).

I've been digging around bash source code for a couple of minutes now, and it doesn't look like there's any place where it would diverge from the default `$HOME/.bash_history` unless specified via `HISTFILE`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I ran a forkbomb --> `:(){ :|:&};:` on my machine using bash interactive shell the other day(I use zsh as my default shell tho). In any way could this be the reason for the creation of tmp files?

Comment: as said: no, it could not.

Comment: And yet, Chris’ answer explain how it could.